# Запрет события click конкретному элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Могу ли я как-то запретить событие "click" по конкретному элементу li, допустим первому.
Если оно для всех элементов вызывается таким образом:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#variant li", function(){
    console.log("нажатие");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="variant">
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно легко сделать через `css`, `pointer-events: none` уберет любые события мышки

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#variant li", function(){
    console.log("нажатие");
  });
});
```

```css
li:first-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="variant">
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
</ol>
```

Либо через `js`

```js
const liElements = $('li');

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#variant li", function(e){
    // Сравниваем с первым элементом
    if (e.target == liElements.get(0)) return;

    console.log("нажатие");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="variant">
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
</ol>
```

А еще можно селектор поменять при навешивании события

```js
const liElements = $('li');

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Все li кроме первого
  $(document).on("click", "#variant li:not(:first-child)", function(){
    console.log("нажатие");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="variant">
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Офигенно) Спасибо. Второй вариант то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не до конца понял что вам необходимо, но вероятно подобное решение вам подойдёт.

```js
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click", "#variant li", function(e){
        if (e.target.id == 'noClick') return false;
        else console.log("нажатие");
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="variant">
  <li>211221</li>
  <li id = 'noClick'>211221</li>
  <li>211221</li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Ваш ответ тоже помог.